# VBA: StrComp - what does the return value tell me?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a snippet of the [documentation of `StrComp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function). What I need help with is what "string1 is less than string2" for the return value means because I don't understand the meaning of "less" and "greater than" when it comes to strings.

[image]

I've tried playing around with it myself, but it doesn't help me understand. Just a few examples:

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print StrComp("ABCD", "abcd", vbBinaryCompare) '-> returns -1
    Debug.Print StrComp("ABCDE", "abcd", vbBinaryCompare) '-> returns -1
    Debug.Print StrComp("abcd", "abcd", vbBinaryCompare) '-> returns 0
    Debug.Print StrComp("abcde", "abcd", vbBinaryCompare) '-> returns 1
End Sub
```

In what sense are "ABCD" and "ABCDE" less than "abcd"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character code for "A" (65) is less than the character code for "a" (97), therefore "ABCD" is less than "abcd". The comparison is made character by character from left to right, so as soon as one is not equal to the other, the relevant result is returned.

Comment: @SiddharthRout it's a gin and tonic actually! Merry Christmas. :)

Comment: Sigh! I quit alcohol couple of months ago :D Merry Christmas to you and your family Rory :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Well that's bad timing!!